# Sequence of random variables depending on another random variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, independence

I am working on the following problem:

> Suppose that $U\sim\rm Unif[0,1]$ and consider a sequence of random variables $X_i$ (which are iid when the value of $U$ is given) with $X_i \sim \rm Ber(U)$ (i.e., the Bernoulli distribution). Let $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$.
>
> 1. Find $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]$.
> 2. Let $S_n = \sum_1^n X_i$. Show that $(S_n + 1)/(n + 2)$ is a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$.

I got stuck on question 1 and below is my attempt:

> For a fixed value $U = u$ and a specific sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^n\in \{0, 1\}^n$ with $m < n$ zeros and $(n-m)$ ones, $\mathbb{P}((X_i)_i = (x_i)_i) = u^m(1-u)^{n-m}$. Thus
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_n] 
> &= \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|X_1,...,X_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} | (X_i)_{i=1}^n = (x_i)_{i=1}^n]\\ 
> &= \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 1 | (X_i)_{i=1}^{n} = (x_i)_{i=1}^n) = \frac{\mathbb{P}((X_1,..., X_n, X_{n+1}) = (x_1,...,x_n, 1))}{\mathbb{P}((X_1,..., X_n) = (x_1,...,x_n))}.
> \end{align*}

But it was at this step that I realized my computation would simply give $u$, for any particular $U = u$. I am confused because generally, $X_i$'s are not independent. Did I make any mistake in my attempt? If so, what is a proper scheme to deal with such questions? Any of your help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditioning on $U$ along with $\mathcal{F}_n$ yields $$E[X_{n+1} \mid X_1, \ldots, X_n, U] = E[X_{n+1} \mid U] = U$$ where the first equality is due to $X_{n+1}$ being conditionally independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ given $U$. I'm guessing this is your "my computation would simply give $u$ for any particular $U=u$."

---

However, the question is really asking for $E[X_{n+1} \mid X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n] = \frac{P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n, X_{n+1}=1)}{P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n)}$. You've written down this expression correctly but computed it incorrectly. The mistake is that you need to integrate over $U$ rather than considering some fixed value of $U$.

For instance, the denominator is
$$P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n)
= \int_0^1 P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n, U=u) \, du
= \int_0^1 u^{s_n} (1-u)^{n-s_n} \, du
= \frac{s_n! (n-s_n)!}{(n+1)!},$$
where $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.
You can compute the numerator similarly.

See if you can then arrive at the final result $E[X_{n+1} \mid X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n] = \frac{s_n+1}{n+2}$, i.e. $E[X_{n+1} \mid X_1, \ldots, X_n] = \frac{S_n+1}{n+2}$.

---

From here, question 2 is simple, since
$$E[(S_{n+1}+1)/(n+3) \mid \mathcal{F}_n]
= \frac{1}{n+3} \left(S_n + 1 + E[X_{n+1} \mid\mathcal{F}_n]\right) = \cdots.$$

Comment: This is quite interesting, since this means that $\Bbb E [ U \vert X_1 , \ldots , X_n] = \frac{S_n +1}{n+2} $, where one first intuitive guess for this conditional expectation could be $\frac 1 n S_n$.

Comment: I got to the insight, that this first intuitive (but naive) guess is false, because the oscillations of this conditional expectation are smaller than from $\frac 1 n S_n$. For example, if $S_n > \frac n 2$, the one would overestimate $U$ by $\frac 1 n S_n$, this value tended to be larger, since $U$ is likely to be larger than $1/2$ in this case.

Comment: @Falrach This is interesting indeed. In fact the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[U \: | \: X_1,\dots, X_n]$ would in Bayesian terms be considered the posterior mean in a binomial model with uniform prior. Notice that the prior mean is $\mathbb{E}[U] = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{0+1}{0+2}$, so the formula even holds for $n=0$. The extra $1$ in the numerator and $2$ in denominator will thus pull the posterior mean towards the prior mean, however the pull gets weaker as $n$ grows larger.